# PHP processing user-friendly formatted prices to standard floats

Tags: php, floating-point, usability, currency, number-formatting

I have a form in which users can enter prices for items. Ideally I want the user to be able to add prices in whatever method feels best to them and also for readability. I then need to convert this to a standard float so that my web service can calculate costs etc.

The part I'm struggling with is how to take the initial sting/float/int of currency and convert it into a float.

For example:

```
UK: 1,234.00
FRA: 1 234,00
RANDOM: 1234
RANDOM2: 1234.00
```

All of those have slightly different formats.

Which I would want to store as:

```
1234.00
```

I will then store the result in MySQL database as a DECIMAL.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment, hence the comment. Perhaps you could use [localeconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to cycle through valid combinations of monetary formatting characters, and plug these into a suitable regex. You'd have to try with and without thousands separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use:

```
floatval($AnyVar)
```

Comment: floatval() doesn't appear to work in an instance where a comma is in the string, i.e. 1,234.00 (UK format)

Comment: You could remove all commas using str_replace, then use floatval.

Comment: If I did a str_replace for commas on the french format though... the number would go from 1 234,00 (1234.00) to 1 23400 (123400.00) so that still wouldn't help.

Comment: I've decided to ignore the french notation of pricing... and just request prices in the UK/American formats. So basically now I remove commas with str_replace() and then use floatval() to check it is a float.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MySQL, use the DECIMAL or NUMERIC type are the correct types used for storing currency.

Float's are susceptible to rounding errors and have a limited precision.

The formatting for display should be handled by PHP.

If storing in DB, you should of course store a currency code - which can be used when retrieving to tell PHP how to display it

Comment: I agree with Brian. Let MySQL handle the currency stuff.

Comment: Yep, I will be using decimal for the storage part.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question though which is about deconstructing the formatting with PHP.

Comment: What if you checked which format is was by getting the 3rd character from the right? If it is a ',' then remove all '.'. If it is a '.' then remove all ','.

Answer (score 0):

In a case where you'd like to accept so many different formats it's a bit tricky to get it right.

Now we can just use a simple regex to get the decimal and full parts of the value:

```
/^([0-9,. ]+?)(?:[.,](\d{1,2})$|$)/
```

The regex will capture the full part of the number + a decimal part, separated with a , or a . and which has one or two numbers.

The capture group 1 will contain the full part, and group 2 the decimal part (if any).

To get your number, you just need to filter out all non-numeric characters from the full part, and join the filtered full and decimal parts together.

If you want to make it more foolproof, you probably should implement something on the client-side to guide the user to input the value in the correct format.

Comment: I had thought about doing it this way... but it seems a bit limiting to the user. I'm assuming most won't read the expected format even if its blatently obvious.

Comment: @diggersworld I changed the regex a bit, it will match numbers without decimal parts and decimal parts with a single number now. By further tweaking you could probably have it match other sort of stuff too if you want.